# Only mouse no windows on second screen after Ubuntu update (using DisplayLink)

Tags: ubuntu, display

After a recent Ubuntu update (X Window Server 1.18.3) the DisplayLink driver does not work correctly: **You can only see your mouse on the second screen but all windows are invisible.** The background is black.

Answer (score 0):

**Fix/Workaround:**

Create a X Windows config file for DisplayLink and disable PageFlip (when using the default driver Intel CPU driver):

```
sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-displaylink.conf

# add this and save with Ctrl+O, leave with Ctrl+X and reboot
Section "Device"
  Identifier "DisplayLink"
  Driver "modesetting"
  Option "PageFlip" "false"
EndSection
```

*This fix comes from DisplayLink. I tried to use the Intel CPU proprietary driver first (which is still activated under "Software & Updates" > Additional Drivers) but this did not fix it for me so I used the second fix, mentioned above.*

Source: http://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/1181623-displaylink-ubuntu-driver-after-recent-x-upgrades)